# Cold contract in bridge

Tags: bridge, terminology

A cold contract usually means that a contract, which makes on most reasonable lines, as the cards lie. You hear people say, "He managed to find a line to go down in a cold contract".

(Note: the meaning could slightly differ based on region etc).

I am curious, how this term came into being. There is a past BBO forums thread: http://www.bridgebase.com/forums/topic/43444-what-is-a-cold-contract/ but that does not seem to help.

Does anyone know the origin of this term?

Comment: Yes; that link is to a rant not much use for anything.

Answer (score 2):

[Official Encyclopedia of Bridge, 6th Edition (2001)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Official_Encyclopedia_of_Bridge#Sixth_edition_-_2001) lists:

> **Cold contract:** Bridge slang for an easily makeable contract.

*Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary, 8th Edition* (c 1980) lists as sense **5 b**:

> **Cold**: certain, sure *viz* The actors knew their lines cold a week before opening.

OED Compact Edition (1928) does not list any comparable sense for the word *cold*.

Comment: Thanks, but I am more interested in the origin, rather than the meaning.

Comment: @Aryabhata: That would seem to be sense **5.b** from Webster's, originating between the 1920's and 1980 during the heydays of Culbertson and Goren. I certainly recall the term being common Bridge slang from the mid-70's in Southern Ontario if memory serves honestly.

Comment: I am guessing it is probably in the 1930s... but perhaps you are right.

Answer (score 1):

The OED does have a related sense: 
'Without preparation, preliminary performance, etc. Usu. quasi-adv.
1896.. "I'm an easy runner till it comes to the high jump and then I quit cold."'
It was also apparently used between the wars for plays that opened without a preliminary tryout.

So perhaps a contract that can be made without any preliminary setting up, or having to decide which course is better,  fits the description. If you want a more precise answer you could ask on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).